# Android: getfromlocationname not returning all locations

Tags: android, google-maps, maps

I am doing a project which use Google Maps. The project requires to give all locations for a address string.

Eg:-
`barbeque nation bangalore` should display all the barbeque nations in Bangalore using overlays. This query is supposed to return 3 places as there are 3 barbeque nations in Bangalore, but it is returning 2 places only. In some other query strings also it is not listing all the places actually present. But when I use Google Maps from the browser I am getting all the results.

I am using `getFromLocationName` to get the locations. Following is the code snippet:

```
public static List<Address> lstFoundAddresses;  
String addressInput = address.getText().toString();
lstFoundAddresses = gc.getFromLocationName(addressInput, 20);
```

Comment: try to use [Google places](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/search) `GeoCoder` will only give area.